# Stop eclipse from automatically importing a particular package

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to stop Eclipse from ever automatically importing (when pushing ctrl+shift+o) a particular package?

The culprit is of course android.R - Additionally is there any reason why you might not want to do this? I always use android.R resources with the fully qualified name, even in a class that doesn't use the app's own resources so I can't see why not?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to the list on Java's "Type Filters" preference page.

Comment: This works but unfortunately also disables suggestions from showing in content assist. Seems like what I'm after probably isn't possible.